# Where to find base type of a class

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

One thing that always bugged me, is that I do not see the base type in Visual Studio.
I just stumbled on this, because I tried to cast a System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem to a System.Windows.Forms.Control

In eclipse the "intellisense" (or whatever it is called) shows me while exploring the members of a class for each member from which base class it is inherited.

In Visual Studio I cannot see the base class, even if I use the Objectbrowser or the help.

The only solution I found is to use at runtime:

```
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType.BaseType)
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType.BaseType.BaseType)
Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType.BaseType.BaseType.BaseType)
...
```

until I reach System.Object().
Is there a way to query the base type tree of a class at Design Time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this in the Object Browser; if you click the (+) sign in front of the type, there should be a folder called "Base Types" where you can explore what type the type inherits from, and any interfaces that it implements.

There is a setting that controls this; in the tool bar of the Object Browser there is a Settings tool menu; make sure that "Show base types" is checked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

View -> Class View

Usually I just do the "Go to Definition" in the context menu though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the class view. Press Ctrl+W, Ctrl+C.

The class view will show you the base types and many things besides.

Answer (score 0):

The online documentation / MSDN gives this for every .NET class

Answer (score 0):

Object Browser lists the base-type, interfaces and derived types (or it does for me - it could be one of many add-ons...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [class view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy6s2t6h(VS.80).aspx) (ctrl+w, c).  For types that are not your own, you can use [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Answer (score 0):

While debugging the watch window will tell you what the base class is.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a great tool for looking at a classes hierarchy, including it's base classes.

You don't have to have the source code, and it can browse through everything in the framework too.